# Angular2 - show component when hover event

Tags: angular

I would like to show component on hover. I tried this but isnt works:

```
 <td #x ng-mouseover="x.isHover=true" ng-mouseleave="x.isHover=false">{{user.Name}}
  <example-popover *ngIf="x.isHover"></example-popover>
</td>
```

Where is problem? Thanks

Comment: ng-mouseover is a angular js event i feel isn't it ? it should be on-mouseover like

on-mouseover='over()'

over(){
    console.log("Mouseover called");
  }

Comment: You probably want `(mouseover)="x.isHover = true"`.

Comment: I would use `(mouseenter)`

Comment: Thanks . The best solution is `(mouseover)="x.isHover = true"`